# Default password not working with SSH

Tags: software-installation, login

I've just done a fresh install on Raspberry Pi Zero W. I wish to run headerless (I don't have a micro USB keyboard or adapter, nor a mini HDMI cable). I've done this numerous times on the "full fat" Raspberry Pi.

- installed the OS to the SD card
- created an empty **ssh** file on the root
- created a **wpa_supplicant.conf** containing the appropriate details including encrypted WiFi password
- waited the commensurate time for it to do its funky thang on first boot.

It has acquired an IP address from my DHCP server, but when I SSH to it, I'm told ***Please note that SSH may not work until a valid user has been set up***. True to form, the default username and password yield up ***Access denied***. According to a number of online guides, VNC should work out of the box, but that doesn't work either.

How do I get SSH'd in, please?

***EDIT***
I found a mini HMDI cable. The screen is stuck at a "Enter new username" prompt. So, I Googled that. It would seem that (possibly as off about April 2022) there aren't any users created yet. Including the former default.

I still have the problem, though: Am I going to require a micro adapter for a keyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the extended features of Pi imager or add configuration files manually before first boot. See e.g. the official docs at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#installing-the-operating-system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent Raspberry Pi OS no longer have a default user or password and require keyboard and screen to set a default user.

There are options in the latest imager to specify settings before imagining (this is far from straightforward but is documented).

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/135703/8697

Comment: I don't have a working SD card. This is a first time install.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a pointer from @Milliways, the answer to my question is "no": I did not need a micro USB adapter.

In fact, the solution is to discard all past knowledge on how to perform this activity manually, and instead rely on the very straightforward **Imager** tool. Once the required OS is selected, simply click the COG icon, select a username and password, select a WiFi SSID and password, and finally flash the image.

Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue so I tried doing it in the imager but when I try to ssh then I get the below error, does anybody know what to do?

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ED25519 key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:n0CDVlaKMYqKA1zPMXqlZUcPWkzvSvnf78dcMMtbKwA.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in C:\Users\wcac1/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ED25519 key in C:\Users\wcac1/.ssh/known_hosts:4
Host key for raspberrypi has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.