# Parameter order in config.txt - Can't change screen resolution

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, config.txt

Does the order of the parameter in the config.txt matter? For example if hdmi_cvt=800 400 60 6 0 0 0 specified before the parameters (hdmi_group=2 & hdmi_mode=87) that specify that a custom resolution should be used.

I am using Kali linux and Parrot OS but they don't have raspi-config. With Kali I am able to get the screen work without making any changes to the config.txt but the screen resolution can't be changed. Even though the screen is advertised as 1024x600 pixels, the actual resolution I see in desktop settings is 1920 x 1080 and the text is really small to read.

with Parrot OS, I am facing strange behavior. After bootup the screen either goes blank or is stuck at rainbow splash. Pi does boot successfully as I am able to ssh into it. So I wanted to set the display parameters but I wonder if there is a specific sequence in which video/display parameters should be listed or do they have to be under a specific group to be properly setup?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear WHY you are doing this. You should only use `hdmi_cvt` if your monitor requires a mode that is not in one of the tables, then it’s possible to define a custom CVT mode.

See https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#video-options

If you use `hdmi_cvt` you should NOT use hdmi_group=2 & hdmi_mode=87.

If fact if you are using a GUI and Bullseye you should not use either. The Pi automatically detects monitor resolution.

**One thing to note ANY display oriented customisations in config.txt and most tutorials DO NOT apply to Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye**. The Pi4 has a Screen Configuration utility which can change GUI display on the fly. This operates independently of the Console frame buffer.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/135703/8697

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question to make it more clear why I am doing this

Comment: I followed the https://learn.adafruit.com/using-weird-displays-with-raspberry-pi/everything-else guide and according to it hdmi_group = 2 & hdmi_mode = 87 needs to be specified to use a custom resolution / mode.  Also the example showed in your link for official rpi documentation uses these two arguments together with a custom cvt mode

Comment: It is your call but I would rely on the official Raspberry Pi Ltd.  documentation rather than Adafruit.

Comment: Again if you choose to use an unusual combination of hardware and OS you will need to explore how they work.

Comment: Yes I am exploring the best settings for the OS other than Raspberry Pi OS. But Could you please comment on my question regarding the specific order in which these parameters/settings need to be mentioned as I don't see them being implemented e.g. a different resolution etc.

Comment: First the commands are not parameters. You have 2 contradictory commands. It is unclear what the ultimate effect will be but normally I would expect the last to apply but AFAIK this is undefined.

Comment: The positional parameters to the commands obviously have to be in the defined order.